# How to print a list from a class

Tags: python, list, class, methods, printing

I've tried diffrent methods to print a list from a class by looping it or changing it for a string. When I change it within a class for a string I get multiple `"<__main__.Card object at 0x00000262D8279820>"` and when I'm looping it within a class I get Traceback `"TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type Card)"`. How can I simply display a list from a class?

```py
class Card:
    def __init__(self, suit, rank):
        self.suit = suit
        self.rank = rank
        self.value = values[rank]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.rank + ' of ' + self.suit

class Deck:
    def __init__(self):
        self.deck = []
        for suit in suits:
            for rank in ranks:
                self.deck.append(Card(suit, rank))

    def __str__(self):
        for card in self.deck:
            return card
```

Comment: What about Card? Does it have `__str__` defined?

Answer (score 1):

You actually never transformed your card to a string in your given example. Here's a way to do it.

```py
class Deck:
    def __init__(self):
        self.deck = []
        for suit in suits:
            for rank in ranks:
                self.deck.append(Card(suit, rank))

    def __str__(self):
        return ', '.join(map(str, self.deck))
```

- `map(str, self.deck)` will transform every element of `self.deck` to a string using their `__str__` method.
- `', '.join(...)` will concatenate every element of the list, separating they with `', '`.

This will work assuming your `Card` class defines a `__str__` method, for instance :

```py
class Card:

   [...]

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.suite}: {self.rank}"
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what a `Card` is, but you can just return the string of the deck:

```py
class Deck:
    def __init__(self):
        self.deck = []
        for suit in suits:
            for rank in ranks:
                self.deck.append(Card(suit, rank))

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.deck)
```

You may need to also implement `__repr__()` to get lists to render your cards:

```py
class Card:
    def __init__(self, suit, rank):
        self.suit = suit
        self.rank = rank
        self.value = values[rank]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.rank + ' of ' + self.suit
    def __repr__(self):
        return self.__str__()
```

Comment: I've tried it but it only dipslays "<__main__.Card object at..." . I edited my question by adding sample code of class Card.

Answer (score 0):

From what I gather you are trying to print the contents of a list. But it looks like the list contains cards of the class `Card`. It is also an object and will return something like "<main.Card object at 0x00000262D8279820>". It seems like you will need `__str__` for the `Card` class too.

Also using `return` will only return the first element as it will exit the block.